# Picking from Custom Priority SQL query

Tags: sql

I have a recordset that looks something like this

```
Tradeid    CUstom Priority
101            4
101            2
101            3
102            6
102            1
102            5
```

I have got my records sorted in custom order of priority 4,2,3,8,5,9,10,1,6,7,11 
What i now want is just the first records of each group
As in the above record set should get filtered to

```
101   4
102   6
```

Rember, you cant apply max or min on custom priority coz it could appear in any form
as 1,5 or 4,2

how would you do this....

Note:

This is the way i have done the ordering
ORDER BY
            CASE CRL.CONFIRM_SOURCE_ID
            WHEN 4 THEN 1
            WHEN 2 THEN 2
            WHEN 3 THEN 3
            WHEN 8 THEN 4
            WHEN 5 THEN 5
            WHEN 9 THEN 6
            WHEN 10 THEN 7
            WHEN 1 THEN 8
            WHEN 6 THEN 9
            WHEN 7 THEN 10
            WHEN 11 THEN 11
            WHEN NULL THEN 12
            END

Comment: It's not clear what are column names and what are row values here...

Comment: Sorry, could you rephrase the question? Are you trying to get the first 4 rows (101, 4, 102, 6) to be different than the rest of the rows? Or are you trying to have the first 4 rows be reported as 1 row ("101 4 101 3")? Or something else?

Comment: I just need the first rows in each group

Comment: You need another column to give you the order you want, since there is no first record or an order on a table.

Comment: i want to avoid that...for it will break a lot of application code

Comment: Lamak has a good direction here. You can add another column to pull out 4, 6 and all of your existing queries will remain the same. Or are you looking for something like WHERE [[Custom Priority]] IN (4, 6) ? This would be less flexible, more fragile, and more obscure, but it would not change any of your app code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want the `MAX` Custom Priority for each Tradeid.

```
SELECT TradeId, MAX([Custom Priority]) AS MaxCustomPriority
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY TradeId
```

Comment: the custom priority order is 4,2,3,6,5,9 ...your query wont work in the case whre i will have 2,3 in the custom priority col

Comment: @vinayvasyani What database engine are you using?, also, are those two columns the only ones in your table?, what defines the order of the row?

Comment: so i have sorted them to my custom order..what i want now is just the first rows of each group...